# JPA/Hibernate Entidade com Collection para ela mesma

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Olá, possuo uma entidade chamada menu em meu sistema.
Um menu pode ser filho de outro menu e assim sucessivamente.
A tabela possui a seguinte estrutura:

[image: Tabela banco estrutura]

A entidade está mapeada da seguinte maneira:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Menu.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM Menu m")
public class Menu extends AbstractEntityDomain implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String id;

private String descricao;

private String legenda;

private String link;

private int ordem;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Menu
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="menupai")
private Menu menu;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Menu
@OneToMany(mappedBy="menu", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Menu> menus;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Grupomenu
@OneToMany(mappedBy="menu", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Grupomenu> grupomenus;


public Menu() {
}

public Menu(String id, String descricao, String legenda, String link, int ordem){
    this.id = id;
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.legenda = legenda;
    this.link = link;
    this.ordem = ordem;
}

public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return this.descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public String getLegenda() {
    return this.legenda;
}

public void setLegenda(String legenda) {
    this.legenda = legenda;
}

public String getLink() {
    return this.link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public int getOrdem() {
    return this.ordem;
}

public void setOrdem(int ordem) {
    this.ordem = ordem;
}

public Menu getMenu() {
    return this.menu;
}

public void setMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
}


public Set<Menu> getMenus() {
    return menus;
}

public void setMenus(Set<Menu> menus) {
    this.menus = menus;
}

public Menu addMenus(Menu menus) {
    getMenus().add(menus);
    menus.setMenu(this);

    return menus;
}

public Menu removeMenus(Menu menus) {
    getMenus().remove(menus);
    menus.setMenu(null);
    return menus;
}

public Set<Grupomenu> getGrupomenus() {
    return grupomenus;
}

public void setGrupomenus(Set<Grupomenu> grupomenus) {
    this.grupomenus = grupomenus;
}
```

Preciso executar uma consulta onde desejo trazer todos os menus com seus filhos, elaborei a consulta da seguinte maneira:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("SELECT m ");
    sb.append("FROM Menu m ");
    sb.append("LEFT JOIN FETCH m.menusFilho ");
    sb.append("WHERE m.menu is null ");//esta linha é porque os menus principais não tem pai

    List<Menu> lista = new ArrayList<Menu>(em.createQuery(sb.toString()).getResultList());
```

Esta consulta está retornando valores duplicados. Para cada menu que tem filhos como por exemplo o menu de permissões, ele traz três ocorrencias do menu permissoes com as collections de filhos preenchidas ao invês de trazer somente uma ocorrência com uma collections de filhos preenchida.

Já tentei usar distinct e ocorre o mesmo erro, tem alguma sugestão ?
Desculpe se o texto ficou grande, tentei explicar ao máximo o meu cenário.

Comment: Você poderia substituir a segunda figura pelo código correspondente? Ficaria mais fácil para testar e pesquisar soluções na internet assim.

Comment: O que é um `AbstractEntityDomain` e um `Grupomenu`?

Comment: AbstractEntityDomain é uma classe que uso para abstrair metodos de toString e hashCode. Para que fiquem iguais em todas as minhas entidades. Só tem uma implementacao padrão de hashCode e uma do toString. Já o Grupomenu seria outra entidade do meu conceito que representa um grupo de permissão que tem acesso a alguns menus.

Comment: Bem, não sei o que poderia fazer para te ajudar. Mas vou dar uma sugestãozinha: Você não precisa do `StringBuilder`. O compilador é esperto o suficiente para saber que a concatenação de strings fixas e determinadas dá uma outra string fixa e determinada. Assim, você pode usar apenas o velho operador `+` para montar a SQL/JPQL sem problema e o compilador já vai montar ele mesmo e colocar a string já completa no bytecode, o que é mais rápido e mais simples do que usar o `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa obrigado pela dica, editei. Caso vá testar, grupomenu é apenas uma outra entidade, que representa um grupo de permissão que teria acesso ao menu. No caso atual pode ser removido para teste porque não afeta este escopo.

Comment: Carreguei a consulta executada pelo hibernate e verifiquei que ele não traz linhas duplicadas, ou seja, o problema ocorre no momento em que ele converte isso para objetos. 
Converti o resultado que vem em uma List para um Set(não permite dados duplicados) e funcionou perfeitamente.
Baseado no pressuposto de que minha consulta está correta posso entender que isso seria um comportamento normal do hibernate ?

Comment: Fala herbert,  blza? Man, creio que ficaria mais performatico e mais facil de debugar se vc usar um algoritmo de recursividade, onde o primeiro metodo chamado pega todos os pais de então chama outro que pega cada filho de cada pai e verifica se esse filho tem filho, e assim vai... creio que vai fazer umas 3 sql. sql1 - pega todos os pais, sql2 checa se pai tem filhos e sql3 pega os filhos do pai.. e assim vai indo e voltando.. Ja fiz usando sql nativo e populando objetos DTO, ficou bem rapido e facil de debugar.. bom fica a diga.. boa sorte... :-D

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o JOIN do JPA foi feito para imitar o JOIN do SQL e esse comportamento observado é exatamente o comportamento do JOIN do SQL!

Um JOIN entre dois menus do JPA seria equivalente a consulta abaixo:

```
SELECT *
FROM Menu a JOIN Menu b
ON a.id = b.menupai;
```

Olhe a seguir, uma tabela exemplo e o resultado desta consulta nessa tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como o JOIN do SQL funciona assim, o do JPA também foi feito assim para que a lógica das consultas ficasse mais parecida com a do SQL.

Para resolver o seu problema é só usar distinct na consulta em JPQL:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("SELECT distinct m ");
sb.append("FROM Objeto m ");
sb.append("JOIN FETCH m.colec ");
sb.append("WHERE m.menu is null ");
```

Esse código funcionou perfeitamente no meu teste e é o jeito normal de evitar os objetos duplicados na lista.

Porém, você disse isso não funcionou no seu código. Então uma alternativa é utilizar um set, que é uma estrutura de dados que tira todas as repetições:

```
SET set = new HashSet(lista);
```

O set vai tirar todos os objetos duplicados ao ser criado. Caso prefira você pode converter para list novamente.

```
List lista = new ArrayList(set);
```